# Is there visual representation in Visual Studio 2013 like in Netbeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans, visual-studio-2013

I want to ask if there is in Visual studio 2013 a visual representation of my application like in NetBeans where i can add thing like containers or controls ex. Button or checkbox?

I know that one is Java and one is C++ (in my case).

[image: My view]

Comment: Yes there is a visual UI editor support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of project that you create, you will be presented with different options to populate the UI. If you create a xaml or winforms project, it will present a toolbox on the left hand sidebar. These elements can be dragged onto your form and events can be added via the properties window on the right hand sidebar.

It's pretty easy to use and master within an hour or so. Don't be afraid to whip up a small test project to sample the different elements available.

**[EDIT]** - Once you have completed the creation of the win32 project, you'll need to add a new windows form. You do this as so:

1. right click on the solution explorer root (possibly called Win32Project1)
2. click the add item on the popup window
3. choose new item
4. select the Visual c++ node->UI
5. choose the Windows Form item and add

Now you will see the form on screen. Next, navigate to View Toolbox (CTRL+W, X). Now choose you control (start off in the All windows forms section). From here drag the desired control onto the form and party on it :). Thereafter, it's just a matter of adding code to the events (or creating class objects and referencing them via the events)

Comment: OK i create new project > Win32 Project >finish and i got only code cant find any "Design" option at toolbox on right sidebar i got nothing and on left i got only Solution explorer i add picture on my question

Comment: Bulit -you'll need to add a new item (in this case,a windows form)- let me update my answer to illustrate this more fully

Comment: Jim Tollan - big thx to you for help this is exacly what i was looking for. Now it's time to start learn more c++. Thx again

Comment: my pleasure, go for it BIG time ;). all the best